# Locate command can't find anything inside Documents folder on mac

Tags: bash, macos, document, locate

As it says in the description. I first check our database is up to date

```
bin $ sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
Password:       #password entered and function executed without errors
```

I then try and search for something inside my Documents folder

```
bin $ cd ~/Documents/
Documents $ ls
    Mamp_workspace/                         Scenarios.docx                          gc01/
Documents $ locate Scenarios.docx   #nothing returned
```

I then try another random folder:

```
Documents $ cd ..
~ $ ls
    Applications/                Movies/                      drawable/                    untitled-2.pdf
    Desktop/                     Music/                       drawable-xhdpi/              untitled-2.synctex.gz
    Documents/                   Pictures/                    dwhelper/                    untitled-2.tex
    Downloads/                   Public/                      linux_ssh*                   website-terminal-copy-paste
    Dropbox/                     Samsung/                     scripts/                     workspace/
    Google Drive/                Sites/                       untitled-2.aux               workspace_copy_to_linux*
    Library/                     android-sdks/                untitled-2.log
~ $ locate website-terminal-copy-paste 
/Users/crashandburn4/website-terminal-copy-paste #correct result returned
```

can anyone help me? I've been stuck on this for a good half hour or so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As pointed out by plundra, that's because the `locate` OSX ships with is old and crippled and doesn't index and/or report files which are not readable by `nobody`, even when run as root. What you can do though is either install [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and then `GNU locate`, or, as suggested [here](http://www.rubycoloredglasses.com/2012/03/locate-and-updatedb-with-homebrew/#comment-337) use `mdfind -name` instead (I don't have an OSX box at hand to test this).

Comment: ahh, so that's why, I'll update with homebrew, I'm not familiar with mdfind, I was using locate for speed reasons, having run mdfind it seems as fast if not faster, I don't suppose you know why that is?

Comment: `mdfind` uses the Spotlight index -- a prebuilt database similar to locate's, except that it includes many file properties besides the name, and it's updated continuously. See [this blog post on SU](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/03/digging-deeper-mastering-spotlight-in-os-x/) for more info.

Comment: According to the blog comment I linked `mdfind` uses Spotlight's index which is usually kept up to date, so you don't need to reindex manually. Thus I would not bother installing homebrew _only_ for an alternative `locate` implementation and stick to `mdfind` and add an alias (`alias locate=’mdfind -name’`). As for speed, since both use an indexing db they should be similarly fast - differences in speed can have lots of different reasons, from different db sizes, index format, sorting algorithm to optimization in the frontend tool (or having the _appearance_ that one is faster than the other).

Comment: brilliant, thanks, very useful. for anyone else's reference you can easily update with macports or homebrew, the package name is findutils and (for me at least) while it could now search the Documents folder I would still recommend using mdfind as described above in terms of speed and effectiveness (there was a subfolder I was searching for that still couldn't be located with locate).

Comment: Findutils with /opt/homebrew/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin/updatedb and /opt/homebrew/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin/locate would still not work for me, but I guess things might have changed in OS X in the last 10 years.

Answer (score 9):

It's because your Documents-folder isn't world readable, which is a good thing, specially on shared systems.

The BUGS section of the [locate(1)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/locate.1.html) man-page explains it:

> The locate database is typically built by user ''nobody'' and the
>   locate.updatedb(8) utility skips directories which are not readable
>   for user ''nobody'', group ''nobody'', or world.  For example, if your
>   HOME directory is not world-readable, none of your files are in the
>   database.

Try running `ls -ld ~/Documents` and you'll see the permissions. Wikipedia have an article on [Unix permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions) if you are unfamiliar with these.

Answer (score 1):

You can do sudo ln -s /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb /usr/local/bin/updatedb to make the updatedb command available

Comment: while this is true, I think it is more useful to use `alias locate='mdfind -name'` if you want to use locate on a mac, as the inbuilt mdfind works well, and there's no reason to keep two metadata databases.